# Nginx - Reverse proxy

Tags: docker, nginx, .net-core, reverse-proxy

I have two docker images one for nginx, the other for .Net Core app both running on a bridge network. I published port 80 in the nginx image and wrote this configuration :

```
    server {
   listen 80;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://172.17.0.3:5000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

and I did expose port 5000 in .Net Core Image. Whenever I call the nginx ip it gives `502 Bad Gateway`. What could be the problem?

Comment: 502 error can come if server(.Net Core) is not running or nginx is not able to  communicate with .Net Core.Please check .Net core docker is running or not (use docker ps)?

Comment: Both Images are running and each image can ping to the other image so they are connected

Comment: curl http://172.17.0.3:5000

Comment: @IAmBatman the application is working, it displays the output

Comment: curl 172.17.0.3:5000 command you are running from host , right ?

Comment: @GirdharSojitra yes

Comment: Did you see any error logs in nginx related to upstream connection ?

Comment: What do you mean that you have exposed port 5000 ? You don't need to expose port in this case.

Comment: @GirdharSojitra there is an error saved in nginx logs, connect() failed (111: Connection refused)  while connecting to upstream

Comment: @GirdharSojitra and i did run curl 172.17.0.3:5000 command from the nginx image and it displays the output as well

Comment: Can you share other nginx.conf file,too?

Comment: Also share both docker command which you are running and which OS being used ?